# App Crash continuously java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

Senerio is like this, My app with Version.1 is present in **priv-app** folder and it is working fine, now i am updating it with new Version.2. App starts from **LauncherActivity.java** and runs without crash. Somewhere in my program a crash occurs with **NullPointerException**, then App exit and when I try to open it starts crashing.
I am using external libraries and checked all libraries in Order and Export
PackageName is **com.example**
Here is the LOG-

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example, PID: 7473
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.LauncherActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.LauncherActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/APP.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.LauncherActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/APP.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.AppApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.LauncherActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: did you added it in your manifest as your launcher activity?

Comment: Yes, it is declared in manifest. Otherwise app wont run.

Comment: show us Your manifest please

Comment: <application
android:name="com.example.AppApplication"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
<activity
android:name="com.example.LauncherActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

Comment: Please see the question. App Launched successfully. But after crash it is not opening.

Comment: make sure your LauncherActivity is in following package com.example.LauncherActivity, i think it is in different pakage, plz verify

Comment: its in the right package.

Comment: Did you find solution?I am also facing similar issue,i updated system/priv-app/ and added one receiver in new version whenver network changes .it is giving ClassNotFoundException whenever network changes.although after rebooting it doesn't crash and receiver works properly

Answer (score 0):

I think it should have to be `com.example.AppApplication.LauncherActivity`

instead of
`com.example.LauncherActivity` 
 in manifest.